# multi class SVM in R - weights extraction

Tags: r, svm

My question is about my 28 feature dataset with  6 classes

1. When running  `t(w %*% t(as.matrix(testset[,2:29]))) - svm.model$rho` for the 6 class problem, I get a matrix showing the testing dataset and the classes minus 1 (5 instead of 6), same as the sample table below. How can I determine the class from this table?

   ```
               V1          V2          V3          V4          V5
   1   3191    172.58302   -1527.0875  -1301.15106 -767.5058   3451.69551
   2   2159    1199.02091  -1782.2845  -1362.27901 -2257.9054  4132.92307
   3   4295    1557.35203  -2374.2095  -1581.37368 -3601.2268  5963.68623
   4   3843    433.74900   -1091.0102  -1296.25825 -1285.6248  3217.86395
   5   4448    1184.22539  -1515.8411  -1708.36731 -2612.3417  4621.73283
   ```
2. How can the above be generated from where the

   - Bias is a matrix (15*1) ... (15 values)
   - Weights is a matrix (5*28)
   - And any new point (x) is 28 features

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Which library are you using? Why not use the `predict` function? And I don't understand point 2.

Comment: I am using the e1071 library and the client need to have the function in excel so he can apply it for future predictions. regarding question 2 the output of the decision values using attr(svm.pred, "decision.values") is the training set with with positive or negative values for each binary classification. So for example in my data set I have 6 classes, Then i will be having 15 values. The question now is how can i generate these values manually.

Comment: Please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see how to make a nice reproducible example.